# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & string'

Tags: arrays, typescript, ngrx, typescript-typings, ngrx-entity

I want to use `Array.prototype.includes` method in my ts file like.

```
const id = this.selectedItem.id;
ids.includes(id);
```

Where `ids` is an array of numbers.
I always get a compilation error:
`Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & string'`

When explicitly transform id to be a number `Number(id)`, then I also see `Type number is not assignable to type string`.
And when I explicitly transform id to be a string `id.toString()` then I can see `Type string is not assignable to type number`.

It is overwhelmig. How `includes` method can be used in TypeScript? How to use it in my example?

**[Edit]** Extended example:

```
    interface State extends EntityState<IItem> {}

    this.stateSubscription = this.store.select((state: State) => state.items).subscribe(
        val => {
            const selectedId = this.selectedItem ? this.selectedItem.id : null;
            val.ids.includes(selectedId);
    }));
```

`val.ids.includes(selectedId as any)` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `ids` as `number[] & string[]`

This means that the parameters you provide to the methods should be of type `number[] & string[]`.

Try declaring it as `number[] | string[]`, which is one of either, instead of both.

Comment: Probably you have a right, but this interface is an `ngrx/entity` predefined thing.
I tried `const ids: string[] | number[] = val.ids;` but with no results.

Comment: Tried `ids.includes(selectedId as any)` but: `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number) => boolean) | ((searchElement: number, fromIndex?: number) => boolean)' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: @krzyhub could you please provide a [mcve] of your issue ?

Comment: @krzyhub I'm not talking about an extended example but about a [mcve] that you make on https://stackblitz.com : without the context in which you're working (libraries, effects, etc.) , I can't really help you more than that

Comment: I think that this case is not worth it. I will try something else than `Array.prototype.includes`, because TS just sucks. Thank you for your efforts.